# Genre of application in iTunes

Tags: objective-c, iphone, itunes

I am installing my own app in iTunes, and found it to be unknown genre. Since my app is an News based Genre, i need to make is shown as a news genre instead of unknown Genre. But my app is not yet launched in App store. whether this is the cause or anything else? please suggest

Any help would be appreciated.

-Sathiya

EDIT:

Thanks for the information. But to be more clear about the question is If you download any app from iTunes means it will based on News, Entertainment, Games, Music Genres. Likewise my appication is a news based Genre. So i need to recognize it as a News based Genre in iTunes. As of now it displays Unknown Genre in iTunes. But my app is not yet launched in App Store.

Comment: Is this the case with Artist, Album Artist, Album and Comments also..??

Answer (score 14):

You don't get to set the genre until you submit the application to the App Store. In the process for submitting an application to the App Store you get to set the Primary and Secondary categories, just like slf said. Before submission, you're app has no genre.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm clear on what you are asking, but when you submit your application to the App Store you will be prompted for the Primary and Secondary category for your application.  Users will see that.

Comment: Would that mean that you can't set a genre (displayed in the "Applications" section of iTunes) for your app before you submit it to the App Store? I'd like to do set it for the beta testers if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is Ad Hoc distributed or Enterprise distributed, this does not let you set the application category and it stays as "Unknown Genre".

We still don't have an answer to that condition.