# How to set the genre of iPad application at development level

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Genre of application in iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460076/genre-of-application-in-itunes)

Hi

I want to set a specific category or genre like "Productivity" of my
iPad Application at development level.
I added the iTunesMetadata.plist in the project folder and set the
genre key as "Productivity" But it does not work for me...
When I drags the app into iTunes, it shows "Unknown Genre".

Can anyone suggest how can I set the genre of my app ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460076/genre-of-application-in-itunes

Answer (score 0):

You would get the option of setting the genre of your app on iTunesConnect when you submit it for approval process